# HttpRuntime Cache stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using httpruntime cache to run a piece of code every 30mins. The site is hosted in a shared environment. It was working fine until last week. No code was changed, but it stopped working.

Other than "Application Started" email, I haven't received any other email. Any suggestion on how to find the issue?

Thanks.

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterCache();
        SendEMail("Application Started");
    }

    private void RegisterCache()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("dummy", "dummy", null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30), 
                              Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, 
                              new CacheItemRemovedCallback(OnCacheItemRemoved));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            SendEMail(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void OnCacheItemRemoved(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        try
        {
            RegisterCache();
            // ... get data from the interweb, email data...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendEMail(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            SendEMail("Cache Item Removed");
        }
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendEMail("Application Ended");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause would be the idle timeout setting in the IIS application pool.
By default it is set to 20 minutes.
This would cause your website to "shut down" and your cache removed event would not fire.